# Angular 4 on click event change button text and style

Tags: angular

I have a component with the following methods

```
onProductAdded(product: ImportList) { // Add an Item to ImportList
   // after some logic add product to ImportList
    this.productIsOnImportList = true;
    console.log('product added');
  }

  onProductRemoved(product: ImportList) {
    this.productIsOnImportList = false;
    console.log('product removed');
  }
```

And on the html template i have

```
<button 
 (click)="onProductAdded(product)"
 *ngIf="!productIsOnImportList"
 class="ui labeled icon blue button">
 <i class="plus icon"></i>
  Add to Import List
</button>
<button 
 (click)="onProductRemoved(product)"
 *ngIf="productIsOnImportList"
 class="ui labeled icon red button">
 <i class="minus icon"></i>
  Remove 
</button>
```

The problem is right now the behavior is global, the click affects all products but i want the click to be private to individual product. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply using `$event` to achieve this instead of having two separate buttons

```
onProductAdded(event){
    if(event.srcElement.innerHTML ==='Add to Import List' ){
      //// perform add action
      event.srcElement.innerHTML="Remove";
    } else if(event.srcElement.innerHTML ==='Remove'){
      //// perform remove action
      event.srcElement.innerHTML="Add to Import List";
    }

  }
```

HTML

```
<button (click)="onProductAdded($event)">Add to Import List</button>
```

Update 1 : Based on comment for the font-awesome icon

```
onProductAdded(event){
if(event.srcElement.childNodes[1].textContent === 'Add to Import List' ){
  //// perform add action
  event.srcElement.childNodes[0].classList.remove('fa-plus');
  event.srcElement.childNodes[0].classList.add('fa-times');
  event.srcElement.childNodes[1].textContent="Remove";
} else if(event.srcElement.innerText ==='Remove'){
  //// perform remove action
  event.srcElement.childNodes[0].classList.add('fa-plus');
  event.srcElement.childNodes[0].classList.remove('fa-times');
  event.srcElement.childNodes[1].textContent="Add to Import List";
}
}
```

**Note : Live Demo is also updated.**

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qe9LPBKYEyaLLQa0569p?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, First the reason for wanting this is not fully achieved by doing this. The product object is not passed. Secondly, as you can see the button css classes and icons are different in each scenario. So this answer won't fully work because I'm not only trying to change the text on product added, im trying to change the whole button.

Comment: @mayorsanmayor hang on for a minute i m working on that only

Comment: thanks for your answer but the solution doesn't exactly solve my problem. How about we figure out a way to do it with *ngIf in the template? Because another problem with your latest update is that the product object is still not passed, there are multiple products in the database. And im also not using font awesome.

Comment: `(click)="onProductAdded($event, product)"` should be your method call in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding a boolean variable to my model class.

```
export interface ImportList {
  id: number;
  added?: boolean;
}
```

then on the component class I changed the methods to

```
onProductAdded(product: ImportList) { // Add an Item to ImportList
   // after some logic add product to ImportList

    //this.importList.push(product);
    product.added = true;
    console.log('product added');
  }

onProductRemoved(product: ImportList) {
    product.added = false;
    console.log('product removed');
  }
```

And in the template i did this.

```
<button 
 (click)="onProductAdded(product)"
 *ngIf="!product.added"
 class="ui labeled icon blue button">
 <i class="plus icon"></i>
  Add to Import List
</button>
<button 
 (click)="onProductRemoved(product)"
 *ngIf="product.added"
 class="ui labeled icon red button">
 <i class="minus icon"></i>
  Remove 
</button>
```

By doing this I was able to listen to clicks on individual products. I hope this helps someone.